# Dealing with multiple users logging in to site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

In my ASP.NET C# website I am attempting to use Sessions to allow users to log in and navigate throughout the secure pages while the session is valid. If for whatever reason they timeout or sign out, they are to be redirected to the landing page. Currently the site only allows one user to be logged in at a time. It seems apparent that the session information is being stored incorrectly, but I don't understand where or why this occurs. If you access the page using another browser, you can see the code pulling information out of the session (like the username) that it should not know.

I want to allow multiple valid users to be logged in simultaneously and have no adverse affect on each other while doing so. If you need further information than the code samples I post below, please ask.

My Login page:

```
//Login.ascx.cs
...
private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == null || e == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Null Exception: Login_Click");
    }

    User user = new User();            
    user.Login(_username.Text, _password.Text);           

    if (user.IsValid() && user.GetIsUser() != false)
    {
        user.Save();
                Session["Username"] = _username.Text;
                Response.Redirect("Secure/Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayErrors(user._validationErrors);
    }
    _errors.Text = errorMessage;
}
```

The welcome page (first secure page a user sees)

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Business.User user      = new Business.User();

   _labelUsername.Text     = MySession.Current.Username;
   _labelCompanyId.Text    = MySession.Current.CompanyId;

   redirectLogin    = "../Default.aspx";

   //redirect if any conditions fail for user validation.
   if (sessionKey != MySession.GetSessionId() || (string)Session["Username"] != _labelUsername.Text)
   {
      Response.Redirect(redirectLogin);
   }
   else
   {
      Debug.WriteLine("Welcome SUCCESS: " +  _labelUsername.Text);
      Debug.WriteLine("Welcome " + sessionKey);
   }          
}
```

And finally the User page that includes SQL Query

```
public static string    dataUsername;
public static string    dataCompanyId;

private const string    _getUserByUsernameQuery = 
@"SELECT [User].[username], [Company].[name]
FROM [User] WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN [Company] WITH (NOLOCK)
ON [User].[companyId] = [Company].[id]
WHERE [User].[username] = @username  AND [User].[password] = @password";

private string          _username;
private string          _companyid;

public User(){}

public void Login (string username, string password)
{
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConfiguration.ConnectionString))
  {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(_getUserByUsernameQuery, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
      if (reader.Read())
      {
        Username        = Convert.ToString(reader["username"]);
        CompanyId       = Convert.ToString(reader["name"]);
        dataUsername    = Username;
        dataCompanyId   = CompanyId;
      }
    }
  }
}

#region Properties
public string Username
{
  get{ return _username; }
  set{ _username = value;}
}
public string CompanyId
{
  get{ return _companyid;}
  set{ _companyid = value;}
}
#endregion
```

EDIT: In response to some of the questions:

```
//in the first accessed page for secure users, before 'Page_load'
public static string sessionKey 
{ 
   get 
   {
      return MySession.GetSessionId(); 
   }  
}
...
//in my 'MySession' class
public static string GetSessionId()
{
   return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
}
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.  Security is _hard_ you should not re-invent the wheel.  Use ASP.Net's built-in membership system.

Comment: parts of this system were built for me as part of a learning assignment for my new job. This is something that was already implemented and cannot change, regardless of whether it is a good thing to do. The site i am working on will never be intended for public use. As a matter of fact a future assignment includes changing how the password is stored, but not right now.

Comment: Search for `static` in your project and tell us what you've found.

Comment: Your `MySession` class is almost definitely the problem.  You should probably get rid of it.

Comment: I've edited the OP to address what Tim and Slaks said. The `static` method `GetSessionId()` is probably the culprit. It fits both issues you guys suggested to check out.

Answer (score 2):

See [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

> A static constructor is only called one time, and a static class remains in memory for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program resides.

The code-

```
public static string GetSessionId()
{
   return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
}
```

Will return the same SessionID for the lifetime of the application.

Like other posters I would strongly recommend you use the ASP.NET built in membership providers rather than try and invent your own, this will be more secure, more widely understood and thus supported, easier to maintain and more extendable.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ASP.NET Forms Authentication.  I bet all anonymous users are sharing the same session object.  You can hook it into your own authentication scheme if something already exists. (passwords in a database or file, for instance)

Comment: They are not sharing the same session. I've checked this through debugging.